# ngOnChanges only triggered on last iteration

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have the following structure:

```
Data-Handling Component
  |
  |-- Grid Component
  |-- Chart Component
```

That is `Data-Handling` Component is the parent of two sibling components: `Grid` and `Chart`.

I have an array of numbers which is shared between the three components via `@Input()` / `@Output` properties.

When in the `Grid` component I update a single value of the array, an `@Output()` property sends the information to the parent `Data-Handling` component, which in turn, sends the information to the `Chart` component through one of his `@Input()` properties.

As such (*I've re-written and skipped some of the code, so some syntactic errors might be present*):

**grid.component.html:**

```
[Not Relevant?]
```

**grid.component.ts:**

```
@Input() gridValues: any[] = []  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

@Output() valueChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

updateAllValuesToThree(): void {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.gridValues.length; i++) {
        this.updateValue(i, 3)
    }
}

updateValue(index: number, value: number): void {
    let updatedValue: any = {}

    updatedValue.index = index
    updatedValue.value = value

    this.gridValues[index] = value

    this.valueChanged.emit(updatedValue)
}
```

**dataHandling.component.html:**

```
<grid (valueChanged)="onValueUpdate($event)"
      [gridValues]="dataArray">
</grid>

<chart [chartData]="dataArray"
       [individualValueChanged]="individualValueChanged">
</chart>
```

**dataHandling.component.ts:**

```
dataArray: number[] = []  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
individualValueChanged: any = {}

onValueUpdate(event: any): void {
    this.dataArray[event.currentValue.index] = event.currentValue.value

    this.individualValueChanged = event.currentValue
}
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
@Input chartData: number[] = [] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
@Input individualValueChanged: any = {}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.individualValueChanged && changes.individualValueChanged.currentValue) {
        let changeInfo: any = changes.individualValueChanged.currentValue

        this.chartData[changeInfo.index] = changeInfo.value
    }
}
```

**chart.component.html:**

```
[Not Relevant?]
```

Well. If I update a **SINGLE** value from the `Grid` to the `Chart`, everything's OK.

However, when I call the `EventEmitter` inside the `for` loop for every element of the `gridValues` array, **only the last element of the array is modified in the `chart` component's `chartData` array**.

So:

- in the `Grid` component I'd have: `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`
- in the `Data-Handling` component I'd have: `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`
- in the `Chart` component I'd have: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]`

Every event fires correctly into the `Data-Handling` component from the `Grid`, but only the last update event goes into the `Chart` component, thus triggering the `ngOnChanges()`.

Is this working as intended? Am I missing something?

Comment: need to debug are you availalbe in remote connection?

Comment: Apologies, but I'm afraid I'm not available under remote connections. Thanks anyway for the offer, though :)

Comment: nothing to get afraid. but still working plunker would help me to debug. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `@Input` updates are done during change detection. `@Output` are processed outside of change detection.

When you trigger an event here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.gridValues.length; i++) {
    this.updateValue(i, 3)
}
```

The following method in data handling component is triggered:

```
onValueUpdate(event: any): void {
    this.dataArray[event.currentValue.index] = event.currentValue.value

    this.individualValueChanged = event.currentValue
}
```

So this method is triggered as many times as you trigger `this.updateValue(i, 3)`. The last value of `event.currentValue` will be set for `this.individualValueChanged`.

Only once all events are processed Angular goes through the change detection stage and updates the input `individualValueChanged` binding which contains the last value.

For more information on change detection read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f). Also read [Two Phases of Angular Applications](https://vsavkin.com/two-phases-of-angular-2-applications-fda2517604be)

Comment: Thank you! Funny how just yesterday I subscribed to your site through Medium :)

Any idea on how to overcome this and force change detection through every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @JSG_85, great, you'll find many interesting and unique articles there. Regarding your question, it should not be be done. It goes against the principles of the framework design. Try to rethink the approach.